# React Navigation proper way to reset stack using Redux

Tags: react-native, react-redux, react-navigation

What is the correct way to get back (reset) to an initial state using React-Navigtion and Redux.

This is my initial state:

```
const firstAction = AppNavigator.router.getActionForPathAndParams('HomeDrawer');
const tempNavState = AppNavigator.router.getStateForAction(firstAction);
const secondAction = AppNavigator.router.getActionForPathAndParams('Login');
const INITIAL_STATE = AppNavigator.router.getStateForAction( secondAction, tempNavState );
```

This is my reducer:

```
export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  let nextState;
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'LOGIN':
      nextState = AppNavigator.router.getStateForAction(NavigationActions.back()), state);
      break;
    case 'LOGOUT_TEMP':
      nextState = AppNavigator.router.getStateForAction(NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Login' }), state);
      break;
    case 'LOGOUT_START':
      // Don't know exactly what to do here
      nextState = { ...INITIAL_STATE };
      break;
    default:
      nextState = AppNavigator.router.getStateForAction(action, state);
    break;
  }
  return nextState || { ...state };
};
```

I am not sure if this will work. I don't understand how React-Navigation deals with this behind the scenes. Does it listen to this type of state change and navigate appropriately or do I need to always run actions through getStateForAction(NavigationActions.something(...), state) ?

```
nextState = { ...INITIAL_STATE };
```

I have done this before when I was not using Redux:

```
const resetLogin = NavigationActions.reset({
  index: 1,
  actions: [
      NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: "HomeDrawer" }),
      NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: "Login" })
    ]
});
```

Do I do the following with the above ?

```
nextState = AppNavigator.router.getStateForAction(resetLogin, state);
```

How do I reset React-Navigation back to the Redux initial state and can I use the const INITIAL_STATE above to do this somehow ?

Thanks,

Warren Bell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wow, no answers. For the record I ended up using:

```
const resetLogin = NavigationActions.reset({
  index: 1,
  actions: [
    NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: "HomeDrawer" }),
    NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: "Login" })
  ]
});
```

and then doing this in my reducer:

```
nextState = AppNavigator.router.getStateForAction(resetLogin, state)
```

I also discovered that using:

```
AppNavigator.router.getActionForPathAndParams('ScreenName');
```

does not get me the correct redux action if 'ScreenName' is a screen in a DrawerNavigator. Using the following gets me the correct redux action:

```
NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'ScreenName' })
```

Hope this helps someone else.

Thanks,

Warren Bell

Comment: excuse me, but what exactly is AppNavigator?